# Continuous Integration - Don't move laravel .env files to azure using bitbucket pipelines

Tags: laravel, azure, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've setup everything for continuous integration using bitbucket pipelines to Azure, but .env files & Vendor autoload_classmap files are moving to production, which effect the production so badly..

How can i restrict this action of moving .env files from bitbucket to azure ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How can i restrict some files moving from branch to production

Comment: Just ignore it using git

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid sending a file but have it commited on your repo just do a rm on the pipelines file before sending it to Azure. You can define different steps for different branches so you can write this just for the production branch. For example on your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file you can have this:

```
branches:
   production: #If your branch name is production, do only on production branch
    - step:
       name: your-step-name

       script:
         - your-steps #Whatever your steps are
         - rm .env #This will remove the .env file
         - rm vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php #This will remove the classmap file
         - send-to-azure #Then when sending your code to Azure the files won't be present
```

This example is very sketchy beacause there are a lot of variables we still need to know like, are you producing artifacts? How is your pipelines yml file organized?, if you could post your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file I could write a more concise example.